# PyInstaller Script Not found Error

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I made a script for an app and it works perfectly, and now I'm trying to use PyInstaller to execute it into an .app. I'm running the latest mac os version. It seems like PyInstaller can't find my script but it's spelled correctly and it actually exists. This is what I get:

```
Air-Andrej:~ Andrey$ pyinstaller -F --onefile bb.py
110 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.2
110 INFO: Python: 3.5.1
122 INFO: Platform: Darwin-15.6.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
124 INFO: wrote /Users/Andrey/bb.spec
127 INFO: UPX is not available.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/pyinstaller", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 90, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 46, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 788, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 734, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 162, in __init__
    raise ValueError("script '%s' not found" % script)
ValueError: script '/Users/Andrey/bb.py' not found
```

Comment: StackOverFlow made the code a little bit smaller.

Comment: Make sure you are in right directory .

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out. It was expecting me to put the whole directory in, so that means that the computer was trying to find the file in the wrong directory or just stopped at a certain point.

Comment: Please update the solution with an actual answer explaining exactly what you did to resolve the issue. The current answer isn't clear and therefore not very helpful.

Comment: You can accept your own answer which will also make it easier for others to find an answer quickly.

Answer (score 0):

```
pyinstaller -F --onefile bb
```

Remove the .py extension because although you have a python script, when you save it from a text editor it does not append the .py to your file. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Check the .spec file to include full path in Analysis.

Analysis(['full_path_to/bb.py']

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me with no complication is to copy the full python file path and paste as pyinstaller --onefile 'full path to the main python file'. I know most of us may think we have already specified the folder and no need to use full file path, but machines sometimes defy those assumptions.

Answer (score -1):

```
Air-Andrej:~ Andrey$ pyinstaller -F --onefile bb.py
```

Rename you .py file
remove the space between your file name
that is between the onefile and bb.py

```
Air-Andrej:~ Andrey$ pyinstaller -F --onefilebb.py
```

it should look like this